# Список всех заголовков окон на удаленном ПК

Tags: powershell

Есть задача получить в массив список всех заголовок окно на удаленном ПК.
Самостоятельно смог получить список окон в массив **на локальном компьютере** следующим образом:

```
[array]$Titles = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTItle} |Foreach-Object {$_.mainwindowtitle}
```

Но как получить список окон на удаленном ПК? Пробовал добавить параметр 
-ComputerName, но в массив ничего не записывается, он NULL

Также пробовал через Invoke-Command

```
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName "PCName" {
      [array]$Titles = Get-Process |  Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTItle} |Foreach-Object {$_.mainwindowtitle}  
   }
```

Но тоже бесполезно и в этом случае массив пустой. Подскажите в какую сторону копать))

Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Comment: Вот тут написано что Peocess.mainWindowTItle не поддерживается для удаленного компьютера, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/%D0%B3%D1%8B-it/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx

Но может кто подскажет обходные пути ?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал использовать утилиту psexec. Тогда вам необходимо выполнить приблизительно следующее: `psexec \\computerName -i -u domain\username -p password powershell script.ps1`

Comment: Проблема не в этом

Comment: Тогда опишите подробней в чем проблема

Comment: На самом деле Vadim Bondaruk прав, как выяснилось это единственный способ. Так как получение mainWindowTItle на удаленной машине не поддерживается https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/%D0%B3%D1%8B-it/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx